# localize winform and change language at runtime

Tags: c#, localization

i have problem changing the language in my form. my texts in my form are all in english language texts. when i choose spanish in combobox, nothing happen. same when choosing french also.my localizable in my form is TRUE. my language is in default. what's wrong with my code? need help. for my project.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "English")
        {
            ChangeLanguage("en");
        }
        else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Spanish")
        {
            ChangeLanguage("es-ES");
        }
        else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "French")
        {
            ChangeLanguage("fr-FR");
        }
    }

    private void ChangeLanguage(string lang)
    {
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            ComponentResourceManager resources = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(UserLogin));
            resources.ApplyResources(c, c.Name, new CultureInfo(lang));
        }
    }
```

my added namespaces

```
using System.Globalization;
```

`using System.Threading;`

Comment: You will have to set Thread.CurrentCulture and probably reinitialize your forms - i think but no guarantees on that...

Answer (score 1):

IYou should change Thread.CurrentUICulture to match the selected culture. Even though AFAIK if you specify which culture to apply in the ApplyResources method that shouldn´t matter, it does matter for localized strings (eg. for MessageBoxes) and for any other forms loaded thereafter.

Also, make sure to also apply new resources to child GroupBox controls, and it works great for me. This would be the code:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "English")
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en");
        ChangeLanguage("en");
    }
    else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Spanish")
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
        ChangeLanguage("es-ES");
    }
    else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "French")
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
        ChangeLanguage("fr-FR");
    }
}

private void ChangeLanguage(string lang)
{
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {
        ComponentResourceManager resources = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(UserLogin));
        resources.ApplyResources(c, c.Name, new CultureInfo(lang));
        if (c.ToString().StartsWith("System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox"))
        {
            foreach (Control child in c.Controls)
            {
                ComponentResourceManager resources_child = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(UserLogin));
                resources_child.ApplyResources(child, child.Name, new CultureInfo(lang));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Probably will be late for yourself, but I hope it helps someone else if so.